# Process.Start() makes a .exe file flash open then instantly close again

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I'm trying to start a .exe file using vb.net. I'm currently using the following code:

Process.Start("PathName")

Where "PathName" is the full location of the file and the name of the file including extension. The file does open, but it immediately closes. It is open for far less than a second but I can see it open. When I run the .exe file by double clicking on it it runs, loads a few things and then waits for further input. Why does this not happen with process.start?

Comment: Please show the code where Process.Start is invoked.  Perhaps you just need to set the WorkingDirectory property to the proper folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Shell("Pathname", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False, -1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to open the string literal "PathName". If the path is in a string variable called PathName then drop the quotation marks:

```
Dim PathName As String = "C:\My Folder\My Program.exe"
Process.Start(PathName)
```

Comment: Nope. PathName has been used to replace the very long filelocation in my program.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg But, does your code actually have the quotes around `PathName`? If so, you need to remove them.

Comment: According to the code that you have shown, you are passing a string literal. Is this the code that is causing the problem or not?

Comment: This is not the problem. In the quotes is the actual address of the file and the file name.

Comment: So you are calling something like:

Process.Start("C:\My Folder\My Program.exe")

?